# Are there still favored of using bluetooth devices today in modern games for multiplayer gameplay?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, bluetooth

I was wondering. Most multiplayer gameplay always favored by Wi-fi during team-up or to compete each other. I know that when in comes in huge groups (say 100 to 500 players or more online) in online games whether it's cooperation or battle, most players relying on Wi-fi to play in very huge group.

What if some persons wants to play in small groups and can be played offline (like in racing games or fighting games for example) using smartphones via bluetooth? The question is that are there most game apps for multiplayer gameplay still favored or popular of using bluetooth when playing in a very few no. of players (let's say only two players) on a certain game?

Also, is it possible to create a game app for iPhone or any smartphones that run on Android that features bluetooth for multiplayer via Unity 3D game development software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Unity, anything the engine itself can't do, can be done with native plugins, so I'd say you can.

However, Bluetooth is designed for master/slave personal area networks, like connecting a keyboard, or a headset to a phone. Not for high speed networking.

I guess you could use the LAP profile, but once again, it is not meant for high speed communications.

I don't understand why you're considering bluetooth, but if you're interested in solving the problem of making a network when no access point is available, you may want to consider the ad-hoc mode of WLAN. You can make networks between devices without requiring an infrastructure to support it.

Some devices even let you create an access point, so you may want to consider that as well.

Comment: The reason I'm using Bluetooth is that it focuses on very few players, about 2-5 players only. Curiously, I was making for some future projects that I wanna create a videogame to jumpstart a quick multiplayer and not some MMO thing and I want to know if Bluetooth is still demanding as Wi-fi for multiplayer gameplay connection purposes.